# Decomposing a DFT into multiple FFT calls

Tags: fft, dft, optimization

I'm using a good fast FFT implementation (vDSP) that will only work on power of 2 blocks of audio data.  Now I have a problem where I would like to be able to apply the calculations to non powers of 2 audio.

Some degree of reading around suggests that I can do this by breaking the DFT into smaller power of 2 blocks.

Can anyone explain how to do this, if indeed it is possible at all? I have been unable to find any explanations of how to do it ...

Comment: [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18201/recursive-version-of-dft-as-presented-in-cooley-tukey-paper/18798#18798) explains the Cooley-Tukey factorization and it has an example of how to compute a length 1536 (3x512) FFT. But you could also just zero-pad your data to the next power of 2.

Comment: @MattL. Cool! More than anything knowing what the name of the algorithm is helps a ton!

Comment: Padding to the next power of 2 doesn't give the same results as the shorter DFT, though.   I've fallen foul of that before   ...

Comment: No, but it is a valid DFT of the signal, just evaluated at a different set of frequencies. It contains the same information as the shorter DFT (i.e. if needed one can be computed from the other).

Comment: @MattL. How would you go about computing the true (ie shorter) DFT from the padded FFT?

Comment: The problem is that there is no *efficient* method to do that. I just wanted to point out that the FFT of the zero-padded data obviously contains the complete information about the signal, so in most applications it's advantageous to use it, especially if you only have a power-of-2 FFT routine.

Comment: up-arrow.  looks like i said the same thing as you, @MattL. 15 hours later.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing to do if you have access to only a power-of-two FFT is to zero-pad your data going into the $N=2^p$ FFT and interpolate what comes out.  i think that's what MATLAB does for `fft()` for non-power-of-two DFT.

Comment: well, that's what MATLAB used to do.  [doesn't appear that they still do that now.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)

Comment: They've been using FFTW [since Matlab 6.0](http://nl.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/faster-finite-fourier-transforms-matlab.html), i.e. since around 2000. Time flies ...

Comment: FFTW does the same thing internally, but it can also handle powers/multiples of 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the material at the following web page would be of interest to you: [Rick Lyons - Computing Large DFTs Using Small FFTs](http://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/63.php).   [-Rick-]

Answer (score 0):

By padding, you are losing some of the information in certain bins. You may also get some measurement errors. Why not optimizing your calculation to support a power of 2 FFT? Play with the sampling rate or the length of data acquisition.